# Access only a part of a survival object

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Using the package `survival` in `R` I generated I Kaplan-Meiser-object like this

```
library(survival)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + sex, data=lung)
```

Using `print(fit)` I get

```
> print(fit)
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + sex, data = lung)

   1 observation deleted due to missingness 
                 records n.max n.start events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
ph.ecog=0, sex=1      36    36      36     28    353     303     558
ph.ecog=0, sex=2      27    27      27      9    705     350      NA
ph.ecog=1, sex=1      71    71      71     54    239     207     363
ph.ecog=1, sex=2      42    42      42     28    450     345     687
ph.ecog=2, sex=1      29    29      29     28    166     105     288
ph.ecog=2, sex=2      21    21      21     16    239     199     444
ph.ecog=3, sex=1       1     1       1      1    118      NA      NA
```

How can I now access just a part of this overall-survival-object? Like print the results just for `sex=1`?

Of course I could do something like

```
fit_sex1 <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + sex, data=lung[lung$sex == 1,])
print(fit_sex1)
```

but using really big data sets it is kind of unfavorable to recreate the survival object multiple times.

Comment: With `grep` you can achieve this. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep`:

```
containsText <- "sex=1"
fit_sex1 <- fit[c(grep(containsText ,names(fit$strata)))]
print(fit_sex1)
```

Comment: I don't know if you can find a more "elegant" way, but this is quite flexible.

Comment: Fair enough. I just wonder if there is an intended way to access the data. Your solution looks like a very good workaround. I'll wait if somebody would like to add another solution. If not I will surely accept your answer!